# Did the Stack Overflow UI get worse after joining "teams"?

Tags: support, status-completed, questions, stack-overflow-for-teams, user-interface

After years of using SO, I got used to the following interface (screenshot from [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tour)):

[image: CV]

However recently I started using "SO teams" and the user interface got less intuitive. In particular, the "Questions" tab in the menu disappeared and it is harder to get a list of new questions posted under a specific tag.

[image: SO]

I can get the old interface back by going to this URL directly: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/r

But is there a way to return the old menu that I am familiar with?

Answer (score 7):

There is currently no way to revert to the old UI once you've joined a team. However, I've added this to our Teams feedback. The left nav is in a state of constant re-design so it's definitely something we should think about.